# I want the 3rd image of every line to be in the row. how to solve

Tags: html, css, margin

I have divided the page 3 part and given 30% of width to every Image and the remaining 10% is divided by both sides of every Image that is 6 10%/6 sides. the answer is 1.6666 but the last image of every row isn't in the same row.

```css
img{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.6666%;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox like this:

recommendation: go with **CSS Grid** if you need a gap

```css
/* CSS */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1%; /* Want a gap? Add the gap here. */
}

img {
  width: calc(98% / 3); /* you got 2 gaps @ 1% each. That leaves you with 98% to fill */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="flex-container">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">    
 </div>
```

This is super simplified. I recommend looking at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for an indepth guide. It will show you how to work with it correctly. I would not recommend styling images directly by their tag, but by their class.

Comment: that correct but i want space between the images

Comment: `gap: 32px` is your friend on the parent element.

Comment: But when you want a gap, i would have recommended to use `grid` instead of flex for this. Because in this case you will have to deduct the gap from the image width or wrap them in a container. making everything more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the fact that the images are inline elements and the linebreaks in the HTML code create a little space in the output.

Apart from the possibility to use other techniques like flexbox or grid to solve this (see other answer), you can avoid this phenomenon in two ways:

1.) put them all into *one* code line:

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.6666%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
```

or

2.) Create HTML comments at line ends and beginnings which "comment out" the linebreaks:

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.6666%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt=""><!--
--><img src="http://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Football-Vector-Illustration.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Is that the only solution

Comment: No, it's not: Look at the other answer. My answer is the solution for when you don't want to use flexbox or grid, and it explains why the problem appears in the first place.

Comment: We can even do it by not giving the spaces between the img tags